# Mathematica has detected an internal error

Tags: plotting, functions, bugs

When trying to plot the following function in version 12.2

```
f[x_]:=x Exp[-x^2]
F[y_]:=NIntegrate[Sign[f[x]]Sqrt[((f[x])^2)/(f[x]+1)],{x,0,y}];
Plot[F[x],{x,-5,5}]
```

this message appears.

[image]

It happens also when using `RealSign`. Does that occur in other versions as well, or just for me?

It does not occur if I change the definition a little and use `f[x_?NumericQ] = x Exp[-x^2]`.

Comment: Mma 12.2 on Linux (12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)): It takes some time to evaluate, but at the end I get the same plot as posted by cvgmt with no error messages whatsoever.

Comment: Get the same error, Mma v12.2 as well.

Comment: With the option `Method->"MonteCarlo"` the error does not occur. So it seems to be a problem with `NIntegrate` in some versions.

Comment: No error with MMA version 12.1 on Windows 10

Comment: No error with MMA 12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020). Mac OS X 11.1.

Comment: The codes as written in the question works for "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)".

Answer (score 2):

`NumericQ` work.

```
f[x_] = x Exp[-x^2]
F[y_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Sign[f[x]] Sqrt[((f[x])^2)/(f[x] + 1)], {x, 0, y}];
Plot[F[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Or

```
Clear[f, G];
f[x_] = x Exp[-x^2];
NDSolve[{G'[x] == Sign[f[x]] Sqrt[((f[x])^2)/(f[x] + 1)], G[0] == 0}, 
 G[x], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[G[x] /. %, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: No, doesn't work for me V12.2, same error message.

Comment: @fwgb see the updated. use ODE method.

Comment: @fwgb All of the two methods work in 12.2.

Comment: No, for me only the second does work in 12.2.

Comment: both versions also work in 12.1.1, the computing time is shortened with  f[x_?NumericQ] = x Exp[-x^2];

Answer (score 0):

Your code without any change produced:
[image]

Comment: Which version do you have?

Comment: 12.2, OS Win 10 64-bit

Comment: @Konstantin It seems that 12.2.0 has different release dates. What is yours? You can use `$Version` to find the date.

Answer (score 0):

V11.3 , it works and no problem.

[image]